# How to Compute Exact Boundary and Inner Loops from a Set of Curves

Tags: algorithm, math, computational-geometry

Given a number of curves (include line segments and circular arcs), how to find the exact boundary and all inner loops?

The picture simply demonstrate the meaning：How to find the inner loops (drawing in green) and boundary (drawing in red).

And Libraries like CGAL is not a good option, I need something that is light weighted and easy to use.

Any ideas, code snippet, further readings, 3rd party codes would be grateful.

By the way, is there some APIs in ACIS that can be utilized? Since I’ve got some experience in this library.

[image: inner loops (drawing in green) and boundary (drawing in red)]

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a definitive answer, but I'm thinking about solving it like a graph.

1. Start by splitting your lines/arcs at each intersection point, so that each line/arc is only connected by its end points (vertex of the graph).
2. Remove any line/arc that is not connected at both ends. They do not contribute to inner loops / boundary.
3. To create the graph, use the connection points of each of your line/arc as vertices, and each line/arc as a weighted edge. The edge weight should be the primitive length.

The boundary is the longest possible path without visiting the same vertex twice (except for start/end to close it).

As for the inner loops, it might be a bit tricky. I'd be thinking of following your edges and always turning 'right' at each vertex you traverse.

Hope this helps

Comment: From graph you described create directed graph so that each egde set two edges in both directions. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059141/finding-faces-in-a-geometric-directed-graph/25088967#25088967).

Comment: Thanks. This idea is somewhat like my first version of implementation, I'm afraid this will work but not effective--- 1200 line segments and 400 arcs would run very long time. 
 Slicing curves may take long time and I found an implementation of balaban's algorithm on google code which is great helpful. But the total running time is still long.
 Any other ideas on optimization?